# BreezingForms Integrator Finalize Code and $this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib');

Tags: php, joomla, integrator, breezingforms

I've started working on a Joomla! project (I'm mainly a C#/ASP.NET kind a guy). I'm using BreezingForms and have created forms, got them working, but now I need to do some additional code in the "Finalize Code" section.

I need to access form elements via BreezingForms(FacileForms) API. Here's what I'm doing, but it chokes:

```
// load the standard Facile Forms library
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib'); // page breaks here.

// get the name of the uploaded file
$filename = ff_getSubmit('someUploadedFile');
```

Now I don't know what goes wrong. The page posts back blank. I'm not sure how to debug this in Joomla. I currently do not have access to the server to debug, so I would need to debug remotely at runtime (not ideal I know). My account is of type Administrator for the Joomla backend.

As far as I know all the plugins/modules are installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a blank page in any PHP code, it's likely that "display errors" is turned off. You'll either want to turn PHP display errors on, or check to see if the errors are being written to a log file. Both of these settings can be changed in php.ini or at runtime with `ini_set()`.

As for debugging, you might want to take a look at [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/). There's a Joomla-specific plugin for FirePHP called JFirePHP. I wrote an article about using JFirePHP which you can read [here](http://www.howtojoomla.net/how-tos/development/how-to-debug-your-joomla-code-with-firephp).

Comment: No, I am not getting blank page, unfortunately. Btw, I checked your article yesterday and it's great, I didn't even know about FirePHP! :)